# Create Applescript to email a file

Tags: applescript, automator

I want to have the Apple mail application accept and email from me and then email a file to me.  For example, I want to send an email with the subject "#FILE myfile.doc" and have the script trigger because of the #FILE tag in the subject, and then email me back the file called "myfile.doc".

The files will always be in the same path, but it would be nice to be able to specify the path in the script so I can create different ones for different directories.

I know nothing about Applescript and have dabbled in Automator.  I only see in Mail that you can trigger an Applescript from a rule.  So I don't know if this can be done in Automator.

Please be basic with your responses because I am a newbie to this.

The purpose is to get a file off my computer when I am away.

Thanks,
ROY

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a mail rule in Mail. Specify your email address as sender and the subject starting with `#FILE`. Let the mail rule trigger a script like this:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        tell application "Mail"
            repeat with thisMessage in theMessages
                set theSender to sender of thisMessage
                set theSubject to subject of thisMessage
                if theSubject begins with "#FILE " then
                    set theAnswer to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true}
                    tell theAnswer
                        try
                            tell current application
                                set theFilePathToSend to (POSIX file (text 7 thru -1 of theSubject)) as alias
                            end tell
                            set content to "And here is your file: " & rich text 7 thru -1 of theSubject & return & return
                            tell content to make new attachment with properties {file name:theFilePathToSend} at after the last paragraph
                        on error errStr
                            set content to "An error occured: " & return & errStr
                        end try
                        set subject to "Re: " & theSubject
                        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theSender}
                        send
                    end tell
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Using the `reply`-handler didn't work, but the `make new outgoing message` did! Specify the full path to the file as subject.

Be aware that this IS a security hole! Sender's email addresses can be faked and somebody knowing this can get nearly every file he (or she) wants. You could specify the allowed folders in this script, i.e. `if theSubject begins with "#FILE /Users/rbarr/Desktop/Available files/" then` or just by adjusting the conditions your mail rule is triggered.

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg